# poll results won't show up

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a poll, but the poll_results.txt file won't get written. I've tried on my Windows pc and my Linux server.
I'm using [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp)

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like PHP and AJAX so far?</h3>
<form>
Yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<br>No:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

poll_vote.php

```html
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/php/poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/php/poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've tried changing permission, but they all looked correct. Is there something wrong with the example?

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all? Can you check the log for any warnings?

Comment: Its working. The problem is with your permission

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7x5Wegj7